# How to convert a String to a float in Python 2.7

Tags: string, python-2.7, floating-point

I am trying to convert decimal geographic coordinates as strings to a float.
The coordinates are in a csv like this '51213512'. With my Python script I am just reading the coordinates and add the '.'. If I am not adding the comma the rest of my script isn't working.

I already tried a few things but nothing worked for me. This is what I got so far.

```
latitude=float(long('51.213512'))
```

The Result is a ValueError:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'Long'
```

Comment: You mention a **comma**. Are you adding a **comma** or a **decimal point** (full stop, dot, etc.)? That should make a big difference.

Comment: I suspect that you're trying to convert a *header* line (possibly with header values "Lat" and "Long") in your input file to float. You need to find a way to skip that header line and just convert the values.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes this was the problem. There were invisible characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not too sure why you are using long in this examply if you want to convert this variable to a float just use the float function on its own, you seem to be confusing the long and float functions. dont use both you will be confusing python (basically dosent know what to do because your giving it 2 arguments at once)

I recommend just using the float function on its own. This will avoid confusion

```
latitude = float('51.2135512')
```

Comment: I am confused because of the traceback. If I am using your code it says: 'ValueError: could not convert string to float: Long'

Comment: @Lukas: Works for me, in Python 2.7.15. Is this part of a larger piece of code? If so, please post the entire function. Just edit your question and add the code.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the 'long' and it should work

```
latitude = float('51.213512')
```

Edit: Okay, since you're getting the coordinates and manually converting to decimal strings, all you need to do is use the code I said originally. The `long` function 
converts integers or strings of integers to `long` types, not float types.

```
>>> long(5)
5L
>>> long('5')
5L
>>> long(5.5)
5L
>>> long('5.5')
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '5.5'
```

Comment: I already tried. But this is the output
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Long

Comment: @Lukas would you post how you're generating the geographic coordinates?

Comment: @Lukas: start Python. At the prompt, enter `float('5.125')` and press return. What is the output you get? If it is anything else but `5.125` something is very wrong with your Python installation.